# Deveríamos colocar [friendly-url] como sinônimo de [url-amigável]?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Teria como colocar *friendly-url* como sinônimo de [url-amigável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-amig%c3%a1vel)?

No Stack Overflow é [assim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendly-url) e pelo que eu sei, seria essa a tradução adequada. Também acho interessante manter os termos em inglês (sempre que possível) como sinônimos dos em português, até por uma questão de localização.

Então, o que acham da sugestão?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se até hoje ninguém achou que deveria criar essa *tag*, não vejo necessidade. Os sinônimos existem para casos onde as pessoas costumam usar mais de um termo para a mesma coisa.

Não vejo vantagem em criar artificialmente um. E por favor não o façam só para criar o sinônimo. Se fosse útil teria sido criada organicamente.

Answer (score 4):

Creio que seja assim porque é em inglês, raramente escuto alguém se referir em inglês sobre isto entre falantes de português. Concordo com o Maniero, se fosse usado muitas vezes seria interessante, mas até o momento não parece ser uma necessidade.

No entanto quero aproveitar a pergunta para sugerir esta *tag* como sinônimo:

- [url-rewrite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-rewrite)

No geral vejo como sendo usada para se referir ao mesmo problema, só veria diferença entre ela e entre a [url-amigável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-amig%c3%a1vel) se as perguntas de `url-amigável` falassem talvez de "o que é *url* amigável?" (o que seria uma pergunta única e então o uso da *tag* talvez fosse quase inútil :/) ou "user-experience", tipo algo assim:

> Qual seria o melhor uso de *url* amigável para o caso X?

O que nem seria programação, mas como volta e meia [ux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ux) é assunto, então esse seria um possível uso, mas seria muito raro mesmo, então pra mim `url-rewrite` deve sim ser sinônimo de `url-amigável`.

Se discordar, dê o *downvote* e por favor **justifique nos comentários**, downvotes no Meta não afetam o score, serve apenas para avaliar se uma sugestão é boa ou não.

> **Nota:** dentro da tag [url-rewrite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-rewrite) existe a tag [url-reescrever](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-reescrever), creio que ambas são sinônimos de url-amigável

Comment: Tendo em vista a existência da tag [tag:mod-rewrite], não vejo motivos para o [tag:url-rewrite] dentro desse contexto de [tag:url-amigável] e [tag:ux]

Comment: Sim, justifiquei voto positivo mesmo

Comment: Acho que não me expressei bem @JeffersonQuesado eu quis dizer url-amigavel isoladamente se for falar de UX e no final ainda seria inutil, na verdade eu estava dizendo que se fosse pra cavar a fundo e procurar alguma justificativa, no máximo dos limites seria essa e no final só seria util uma ou duas vezes, depois volta a ser inutil, o que eu quero dizer é que url-rewrite e url-amigavel em "programação" são a mesma coisa.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sobre mod_rewrite, só como opinião, nesse caso desta tag eu vejo ela sendo exclusiva com problemas do módulo, para perguntar como reescrever não vejo sentido de uso, me parece um uso errado na verdade. Creio que mod_rewrite seria para habilitar e/ou suporte do mesmo.